# Pythonのシングルクォーテーションと組み込み関数str()の違い

Tags: python, string

Pythonのシングルクォーテーションと組み込み関数のstr()の違いについて知りたいです．

```
s1 = '{"input":{"action":"read","role":"User","request":["gender","address","birthDate","familyName","telephone"]}}'

s2 = str({"input":{"action":"read","role":"User","request":["gender","address","birthDate","familyName","telephone"]}})

s1 == s2
->False
```

となるのですが，なぜそうなるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

前者(`s1`)は前後をシングルクォーテーションでくくることで、中身がどのようなものであろうと単純に文字列を宣言しています。
後者(`s2`)は一旦[`dict`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict)オブジェクトを作り、それを[`str`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/stdtypes.html#str)関数で文字列化しています。

後者の処理では`dict`から`str`への型変換が発生するため、型変換時に整形処理が入るので`s1`と`s2`が同一の文字列ではなくなります。

下記のコードを実行してみてください。

```
s1 = '{"input":{"action":"read","role":"User","request":["gender","address","birthDate","familyName","telephone"]}}'
s2 = str({"input":{"action":"read","role":"User","request":["gender","address","birthDate","familyName","telephone"]}})

print(s1 == s2) # False

print(s1) # {"input":{"action":"read","role":"User","request":["gender","address","birthDate","familyName","telephone"]}}
print(s2) # {'input': {'action': 'read', 'role': 'User', 'request': ['gender', 'address', 'birthDate', 'familyName', 'telephone']}}

print(s1 == s2.replace(" ", "").replace("'", '"')) # True
```

実行結果を見ると、整形有無で文字列が変わっていることが分かります。

```
False
{"input":{"action":"read","role":"User","request":["gender","address","birthDate","familyName","telephone"]}}
{'input': {'action': 'read', 'role': 'User', 'request': ['gender', 'address', 'birthDate', 'familyName', 'telephone']}}
True
```

なお、なぜ整形時にくくり文字がシングルクォーテーションに変わって出力されるのかについては、公式資料の[3.1.2. 文字列型 (string)](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings)から仕様が読み取れます。

> 対話的インタプリタが文字列を出力するとき、出力文字列は引用符に囲まれ、特殊文字はバックスラッシュでエスケープされます。出力文字が入力とは違って見える (囲っている引用符が変わる) こともありますが、その 2 つの文字列は同じ文字列です。文字列が単引用符を含み二重引用符を含まない場合、二重引用符で囲われ、それ以外の場合は単引用符で囲われます。

**参考資料**

- [**str** and single vs double quote behavior in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9830522)

Answer (score 0):

s2は，辞書の文字列表現です．

> If neither encoding nor errors is given, str(object) returns type(object).**str**(object), which is the "informal" or nicely printable string representation of object.

【引用】[組み込み型 --- Python3ドキュメント](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict#string-methods:%7E:text=If%20neither%20encoding,repr(object).)

そのため，辞書の中身が少し**整形**されて出力されます．

恐らく期待する入出力はこちらです．

```py
>>> s1 = "{'input': {'action': 'read', 'role': 'User', 'request': ['gender', 'address', 'birthDate', 'familyName', 'telephone']}}"
>>> s2 = str({"input":{"action":"read","role":"User","request":["gender","address","birthDate","familyName","telephone"]}})
>>> s1 == s2
True
```